# Select associated model with foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "endorser_id"
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "endorsee_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Contains a name attribute

  has_many :endorsements, foreign_key: "endorser_id"
  has_many :endorsements, foreign_key: "endorsee_id"
end
```

I want to get the name of the endorser. When I do `endorsement.user.name` I receive the `endorsee_id`'s name when I really want the `endorser_id`'s name. How would I do this in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorser, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "endorser_id"
  belongs_to :endorsee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "endorsee_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Contains a name attribute
  has_many :endorsements, foreign_key: "endorser_id"
  has_many :endorsements, foreign_key: "endorsee_id"
end

endorsement.endorser.name
```

Comment: CDub's answer is better -- the User model also contains duplicated references that need to be changed.

Comment: @AndyV yes, but think of the joy & self-satisfaction OP experienced when he moved on to the next error and discovered he could apply his new found knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to rename the `name` part of the `belongs_to` and `has_many` to be unique, then append `class_name:` to the relation so Rails knows which model to look at:

```
class Endorsement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :endorser, foreign_key: "endorser_id", class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :endorsee, foreign_key: "endorsee_id", class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Contains a name attribute

  has_many :has_endorsed, foreign_key: "endorser_id", class_name: "Endorsement"
  has_many :endorsements, foreign_key: "endorsee_id", class_name: "Endorsement"
end
```

This will allow you to do all of the following:

```
User.first.has_endorsed
User.first.endorsements
Endorsement.first.endorser
Endorsement.first.endorsee
```

Comment: I like the trick with adding the `:has_endorsed` and `:endorsements` argument in the `has_many` method. But shouldn't `class_name` refer to `Endorsement` and not `User` in the user model?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are overwriting the relationship. You will need to use the `class_name` parameters. Something like this.

```
belongs_to :endorser, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'endorser_id'
belongs_to :endorsee, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'endorsee_id'
```

Same goes for the user model.

```
has_many :endorsers, class_name: 'Endorsement', foreign_key: 'endorser_id'
has_many :endorsees, class_name: 'Endorsement', foreign_key: 'endorsee_id'
```